# MySQL YEAR() equivalent in Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

With MySQL, I can use the [`YEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function like this to filter by the year of a date field in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT noworkorder FROM workorders WHERE YEAR(date)=2015;
```

In Laravel, I can of course achieve the same thing with a [raw expression](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects):

```
$data = DB::table('workorders')
       ->select('noworkorder')
       ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(date)=2015'))
       ->orderby('noworkorder', 'desc')
       ->get();
```

But is there a way to do this without raw expressions?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The query builder has a [`whereYear`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereYear) method:

```
$data = DB::table('workorders')
   ->select('noworkorder')
   ->whereYear('date', '=', 2015)
   ->orderby('noworkorder', 'desc')
   ->get();
```

Comment: There is any way to apply ->whereYear for all application quires, i mean if I want to put specific year on session to get only records created on this year for all models?